# how to plot and filling numbers in 3d array in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

suppose you have a 3D figure that I have attached the screenshot in the below, how to fill the number in this 3d and plot it out, your kind response will be appreciated.
how to plot the below image in python with filled data which is already filled in the below 
[image: the image will describe a 3d multidimensional]

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself, post your code, and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a multi dimensional [Jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Notice the following:

face 1: 4 x 5 (front)

face 2: 3 x 5 (top)

face 3: 3 x 3 (left)

You can immediately deduce the other 3 faces of course

face 4: 4 x 5 (back)

face 5: 3 x 5 (bottom)

face 6: 3 x 3 (right)

After you got that, you just have to create the arrays according to the size specified. There are many ways to go about doing this but i will stick to the most basic.

For instance to get the front and back,

```
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,4):
        x = []
        for k in range(0,5):
            x.append(0)
        arr.append(x)
        x = []
    JointArr.append(arr)
    arr = []
```

You iterate twice (one for front and one for back) and then iterate according to the dimension (4x5). Therefore, the whole implementation will look something like this:

```
JointArr = []

arr = []
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,4):
        x = []
        for k in range(0,5):
            x.append(0)
        arr.append(x)
        x = []
    JointArr.append(arr)
    arr = []

arr = []
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        x = []
        for k in range(0,5):
            x.append(1)
        arr.append(x)
        x = []
    JointArr.append(arr)
    arr = []

arr = []
for i in range (0,2):
    for j in range(0,3):
        x = []
        for k in range(0,3):
            x.append(2)
        arr.append(x)
        x = []
    JointArr.append(arr)
    arr = []

print(JointArr)
```

This will give you something like:

[image: output]

This is a simplified version of course. You can consider using numpy or other shorthands after you get the gist of what is going on.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind response dear Jackson , but how to plot this array to be filled in the 3D image which I have attached  in the above  like there is 57,61,7,26 and other rows also, need to plot the exact form, i have worked a lot with array and i got output with 3-dimensional, but i tried to print out the 3d image with the filled number, unfortunately, i couldn't , there is another way to plot the image please let me know , thanks once again fro your response here